# Measuring body size in flies/insects

Tags: entomology, drosophila, morphology, methods

> "Mesothorax length (the distance from the tip of the scutellum to the
>   most anterior part of the mesothorax)"

From [Bergland et al 2008.](http://www.genetics.org/content/180/1/567.long)

Would that be this distance (green line)?

[image]

If not, how would you describe that distance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are correct, but I'm not an expert in Diptera/Drosophila morphology. Since the prothorax (pronotum) and metathorax are greatly reduced in flies, you mostly see the mesonotum in dorsal view, and this includes the scutellum. Personally, I think it would have been more accurate of them to label this structure **mesonotum**, or at least *dorsal mesothorax length*, since *mesothorax* could just as well imply a ventral view (mesosternum).

More information can be found at this webpage: [*Flies - Morphology and anatomy: Thorax*](http://www.giand.it/diptera/morph/?id=5&lang=en), which state that:

> The mesonotum occupies most of dorsal view of the thorax. In order anteroposterior we can identify four parts, called as follow (McAlpine, 1981): prescutum, scutum, scutellum, and postnotum. The scutum is the most large, condition considered apomorphic for the entire order of Diptera.

Also see this picture of the mesonotum from [diptera.net](http://www.diptera.info/infusions/terms/terms.php?op=view&id=5)

[image]